# Google api key not working properly shows empty google map screen

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-api

I am using google maps API, and I am having issues while creating a release APK. I have a problem with my Google Maps API key. Could you help me?

***Code***

**Androidmainfest.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.placement.travelcompanier">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="A*zaS**********************************" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**google_maps_api.xml**

```
<resources>
    <!--
    TODO: Before you release your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

    To do this, you can either add your release key credentials to your existing
    key, or create a new key.

    Note that this file specifies the API key for the release build target.
    If you have previously set up a key for the debug target with the debug signing certificate,
    you will also need to set up a key for your release certificate.

    Follow the directions here:

    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup

    Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.
    -->
    <string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">A*zaS**********************************</string>
</resources>
```

**mapActivity.java**

```
package com.example.placement.travelcompanier;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(9.883813, 78.081907);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(9.883813,78.081907)).title("My first marker"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(9.883813,78.081907)));
    }
}
```

**Screen shot:**
(Its shows blank map page)

[image]

Comment: check your log message, google maps always log a message if it failed to load maps along with a clue of how to fix the situation...

Comment: I can't find my solution still

Comment: Did you find the answer? as it mentioned in you google_maps_api.xm file this api key is just for release and you must set for debug version too

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your API Key is for release mode

Comment: I verified it... Still I have same Issue